# Why can't I save my AppointmentsSearchEventArgs to variable?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, variables, appointment

I have a rather simple problem (I bealive). I have this method:

```
   void appointments_SearchCompleted(object sender, AppointmentsSearchEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Results.Count() == 0)
        {
            results = "no events for the selected day";
            //MessageBox.Show(results);
        }
        else
        {
            results = e.Results.Count() + " events found";
            sourceItem = e.Results;

            //MessageBox.Show(results);
        }
    }
```

And I can't "save" both `results` and `sourceItem` variables(which are class fields).
The Message box inside this method shows everything correct, howerver, on the outside `results` reverts to the default value.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: I didn't get how ansynch download works. 
In my case I had to create a reference to my MainPage class, and bind items in `appointments_SearchCompleted` method.

Simple as that.